# Next event prediction

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I've got a list of a number of events and the time they've happened. All the time stamps are in half hours:

```
{ 1, 2013-10-11 23:00 }, 
{ 2, 2013-10-11 23:30 }, 
{ 1, 2013-10-12 02:30 }, 
{ 3, 2013-10-12 04:30 },
[...]
{ 1, 2013-12-05 17:30 }
```

I would like to calculate the likeliness of an event happening in the next 24 hours (differentiated per half hour) based on this historic data. How would I go about? Are there algorithms that will take historic patterns in account?

Comment: You want to solve a distribution fitting problem. The results depend on much more than your experimental data.

Comment: In this case I've only got this data and I try to find a pattern or see if a pattern is present. What data is missing?

Comment: You'll need some sort of mathematical model for $E_1, E_2, E_3$ (events). For example their distribution. Do you expect them to be uniformly distributed (Time between distinct occurences of $E_i$ is roughly constant) or any other distributions (normal distribution, poisson, ...)  
It shoud greatly help to describe the physical attributes of your events.

Comment: I've got this graph for each day: http://screencast.com/t/oXgqPS2lhJV. I'll look into the distribution.